# How to access global $PATH binaries when running as no-home user via sudo?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ubuntu, path

I am running some commands with `sudo -u www-data {command}` to execute some web-server-context-only operations. Even through I have NodeJS installed globally and available in `$PATH` of root, this fails when running the above because `www-data` has a different path: `/usr/local/bin`. If I symlink the node from root's `.nvm` folder into `/usr/local/bin`, `www-data` can find it but has no permission to run it.

I'm wondering what the best approach is to run a globally installed binary from a no-home user like `www-data`.

For context: I'm doing this because I need to call a JS script from within a PHP application, so PHP (running as user `www-data`) needs to be able to call `node`, but must not be a real user people can log in as, for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symlinking into `/usr/local/bin` where the `www-data` non-user **does** have access will keep the permissions of the original, and the original is in the `root` context. Naturally, `www-data` cannot penetrate that namespace without `sudo`, which defeats the purpose.

The way to solve this is to install the binaries into `/usr/local/bin` directly, not symlinking them. That way there's no overstepping of permissions. If `node` is installed with `nvm` just copying that binary into `/usr/local/bin` will be enough.